# Aligning H1 with CSS with relative alignment

Tags: html, css

So I have a DIV tag with a background image:

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="pagebar jquery">
    <h1>JQuery Demonstrations</h1>
  </div>
</a>
```

And the applied CSS to it is:

```
.pagebar {
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
height: 200px;
border:1px solid black;
clear: both;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:x-large;
-webkit-filter: blur(0px);
filter: blur(0px);
margin-top:20px;
}
.pagebar:hover {
border:1px solid black;
-webkit-filter: blur(1px);
filter: blur(1px);
}
```

I wanted to make the text 'JQuery Demonstrations' float to the right side of the background image. However when i change the code in the jquery class:

```
.jquery {
background-image: url(file:///C|/Users/James/Desktop/Website/Images/JQuery.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 70% 100%;
background-position:left;
}
.jquery h1 {
width: 40%;
position:relative;
top: 5%;
bottom: auto;
right: auto;
left: 50%;
}
```

With the values of 'left: auto' and 'right: 10%' the text disappears off the left side of the div. Am I missing something or formatting it wrong? I tried changing the width since before that took the whole width of the div but there seems to be no change.

Answer (score 0):

The `h1` is a block element, which takes up the whole width of the window by default. `position: relative` doesn't change that.

So pushing if to the left by setting the `right` property, even by as little as 10%, does push it partially out of the window, yes. `right` doesn't only push the right side, it pushes the whole block. Or to put it another way, `right: 10%` does exactly the same as `left: -10%` on a relatively positioned block.

Now if all you want is the text to be displayed on the right side of the window, `text-align:right` would suffice, without need for positioning.
But if you want the text to be displayed entirely to the right of the background picture, then give it `left:70%` and `width:30%`. Note, however, that the text is rather large and won't always fit in 30% of the window width, and it will overflow out of it.

```css
.pagebar {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  clear: both;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: x-large;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.pagebar:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}
.jquery {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/1000/200') no-repeat;
  background-size: 70% 100%;
  background-position: left;
}
.jquery h1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 70%;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="pagebar jquery">
    <h1>JQuery Demonstrations</h1>
  </div>
</a>
```